# Ionic 2 AWS Device Farm Appium Test NG

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, appium, aws-device-farm

I have configured AWS Device Farm to run automated tests for my app.

I successfully ran tests using the `Built-in Explorer` and `Built-in Fuzz` test types following [this post](http://blog.ionic.io/test-your-ionic-app-on-real-android-and-ios-devices-with-aws-device-farm/).

Now I would like to use the Appium Test NG type. I have installed the appium module and got it running:

```
[Appium] Appium REST http interface listener started on 0.0.0.0:4723
```

But what now ? How can I write and use a test for ionic 2 use?

It is said [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/fr_fr/devicefarm/latest/developerguide/test-types-android-appium-java-testng.html) that:

> Your Android Appium Java TestNG tests must be contained in a .zip file" and they point to Appium's official website for further explanations on how to use appium with android or ios devices.

The explanations are very unclear to me though and I'm quite stuck right now.

Has anyone ever tried this out ?

Answer (score 1):

Am assuming that you are familiar with Maven. If not, then you should spend some time to get yourself familiarised with Maven before you proceed further with the instructions link

The instructions link is complete and explains what you need to do, in order to create a zip of your Java TestNG tests (They are basically hinting at the set of TestNG test methods that you wrote in Java in order to automate your testcases for your Android App )

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/fr_fr/devicefarm/latest/developerguide/test-types-android-appium-java-testng.html

The instructions also tells you how to upload your tests as well.

If you would like to know how to get started with Appium and Java, please refer here : https://appium.io/slate/en/tutorial/android.html?java#automating-a-simple-action